# Issues with Returning Array

Tags: java, arrays

So I was tasked with asking the user to input 10 numbers into an array and then printing the numbers in order and reverse order using a tester class and not just the main.

I'm having problems with how to return the array that has been passed. Here's my code so far:

```
public class PrintIt
{
   static int[] numbers = new int[10];
   static int i = 0;

   public static int PrintOrder()
   {
       System.out.println("\nList of numbers in order: \n");
       for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
       {
           System.out.println(numbers[i]);
       }

       return ;
   }

   public static int PrintReverse()
   {
       System.out.println("\nList of numbers in reverse order: \n");
       for (int i = numbers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
       {
           System.out.println(numbers[i]);
       }

       return ;
   }
}
```

and the tester class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PrintItTester
{
   public static void main (String [] args)
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      int i = 0;
      int[] numbers = new int[10];

      System.out.println("\nPlease input " + 10 + " numbers.");

      for (i=0; i < numbers.length; i++)
      {
          PrintIt.numbers[i] = input.nextInt();    
      }

      System.out.print(PrintIt.PrintOrder());
      System.out.print(PrintIt.PrintReverse());
   }
}
```

When I run the code with numbers[i] in the return it reads i as being 0 and only outputs the first element in the array. I've looked for a long time and I can't figure this out.

I know, obviously, that there needs to be something returned, but whatever I put doesn't work. For example, when I try to return the array, numbers[i], it only returns the first element because the variable has a value of 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems in your code:

- The declaration `int[] numbers = new int[10];` in the `main` is useless. Remove it, and replace `numbers.length` with `PrintIt.numbers.length`
- Your methods return `int`s, not arrays. Make them `void`, and call them without `System.out.print`.
- Remove the unnecessary `return` statements from the `PrintOrder` and `PrintReverse` methods.

This should fix the problem ([demo](http://ideone.com/At5WVK)).

Comment: That did it.

I wasn't sure whether or not I needed to define numbers[] in the main, so I did it to be safe. For that reason, I kept numbers.length in the main as well.

I had a feeling I needed to get rid of the return by using void but couldn't manage to put 2 and 2 together.